# Return multiple values from list comprehension if any value matches condition

Tags: python

Have array of dictionaries:

```
a = [{'id': 1, 'k': 1}, {'id': 2, 'k': 2}, {'id': 3, 'k': 3}]
```

How to return value of `id` key and value of `k` if any `k` matches condition?

Trying like:

```
return [i['id'], i['k'] if any(i['k'] == 2 for i in a) else fail('fail')]
```

Comment: That's currently *not* a list comprehension, and `i` will take the last value it was in the loop in `any`. It's not clear what output you expected instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `any` because that checks the full list and returns true if any match, rather than returning the specific item which matches.

Do the list comprehension with a check for each 'k':

```
>>> a = [{'id': 1, 'k': 1}, {'id': 2, 'k': 2}, {'id': 3, 'k': 3}]
>>> [(x['id'], x['k']) for x in a if x['k'] == 2]
[(2, 2)]
```

This will return multiple values if more than one `'k'` matches:

```
>>> a = [{'id': 1, 'k': 1}, {'id': 2, 'k': 2}, {'id': 3, 'k': 3}, {'id': 7, 'k':2}]
>>> [(x['id'], x['k']) for x in a if x['k'] == 2]
[(2, 2), (7, 2)]
```

For a missing value, you'll get an empty list. If you want a 'fail' or some random text instead, which is *highly **not** recommended*, do:

```
>>> [(x['id'], x['k']) for x in a if x['k'] == 9] or 'fail'
'fail'
```

And if you wanted each dict that matches, the expression is only the 'x' which is the list items (dicts) which matche:

```
>>> [x for x in a if x['k'] == 2] or 'fail'
[{'k': 2, 'id': 2}, {'k': 2, 'id': 7}]
>>> [x for x in a if x['k'] == 9] or 'fail'
'fail'
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to use `any()` here, as you only need to check one `'k'` key in each dictionary, which must be unique to begin with.

First break down the problem into simple code, then worry about list comprehensions later:

```
a = [{'id': 1, 'k': 1}, {'id': 2, 'k': 2}, {'id': 3, 'k': 3}]

result = []
for d in a:
    if d['k'] == 2:
        result.append((d['id'], d['k']))

if result:
    print(result)
else:
    print('fail')
```

Which Outputs:

```
[(2, 2)]
```

You can easily construct a working list comprehension from here, as shown in @aneroid's answer.